# ArgumentOutOfRangeException after editing a page

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

I am replacing a colleague for the support of a SharePoint 2010 intranet.
I have edited a page to move a webpart below another webpart.
An ASP .Net exception page has been displayed after clicking the "Stop Editing" button :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.get_Item(Guid storageKey) +582
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ApplyChangeList(String changeString) +26841168
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +517
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Does anyone know why ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated